# mysql not working in windows cmd

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added mysql path to path in Environment Variables like this

[image]

But when i use mysql commands in windows command line it give me this error

[image]

I already restarted windows many times and still not working i think there is something missing

Comment: Find out, where mysql program is located. Try to start it with the full path. Then if it's ok, add it's path to PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the MySQL /bin to your PATH.  That's where the command .exe files live.

The PATH environment variable tells Windows where to look for executables when you invoke them without their full path.  It won't infer /bin for you.  You have to be explicit.